# Inserting a node in a binary search tree

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, binary-search-tree

This is the code I have declared, it seems there's a problem with the insert function and I dont get it. And it sure gets depressing for a beginner. So, this is the struct node pointer that I declared globally,

```
struct node{
  int data;
  struct node *left;
  struct node *right;
};
```

This is the root node I declared globally,

```
struct node *root=NULL;
```

This is the insert function that I have declared

```
int insert(struct node* p, struct node *newnode){
    if(p==NULL){
        p=newnode;
        p->left=NULL;
        p->right=NULL;
    }
    else{
        if(newnode->data<p->data){
            insert(p->left, newnode);
        }
        else if(newnode->data>p->data){
            insert(p->right, newnode);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And this is how I called the insert function in the main()

```
struct node *newnode;
while(1){
  switch(n){
    case 1:
      newnode=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
      printf("Enter the element: ");
      scanf("%d", &newnode->data);
      insert(root, newnode);
    default:
      return 0;
  }
}
```

Here I dont find anything wrong in my code, but i keep getting the segmentation error (code dumped) in the insert function. Can anyone please tell me what is the error in this code?

Comment: You should allocate a new node for each new entry in the loop.

Comment: @Tarik but then it is supposed to not dump atleast for the first iteration right

Comment: if p is null, you null out newnode.

Comment: You are right, it was just a remark.

Comment: Instead of allocating the new node in the loop, do it in the insert function. Just pass the data. Also, return the root. Your calls should then be `root = insert(root, data);`

Comment: You do not handle the case where `newnode->data == p->data`

Comment: @Tarik It doesn't work.. returning the root and not allocating the memory for new node in the loop, I tried it in the way you suggested just now. Also if there is a condition 'newnode->data == p->data' where will the new node get inserted?

Comment: You can use >= instead of >

Comment: Allocating the node inside the insert function should work. Why not? Show revised code.

Comment: well it gives me a different error.. that is "expected declaration specifiers before 'if'", I allocated the node inside if(p==NULL)

Comment: I meant this: `int insert(struct node* p, int newValue)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225348/discussion-between-ananya-and-tarik).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proposed code:

```
int insert(struct node* p, int value){
    if (p==NULL) {
        p = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        p->data = value;
        p->left=NULL;
        p->right=NULL;
    }
    else if(value < p->data)
            p->left = insert(p->left, value); // p->left will only be modified if it is null, otherwise it will stay as is
    else if(value >= p->data)
            p->right = insert(p->right, value); // p->right will only be modified if it is null, otherwise it will stay as is
             
    return p;
}
```

Comment: I made a little change in case 1 of switch in the code too.. that is root=insert(root, value) and I get the desired output but I am confused now, how does it work? now root wouldn't be pointing to the top node right it'll be pointing the newest node doesn't it??

Comment: root always points to the top node. The top node will be changed from null to a pointer to the new node upon the first insert only. After that, either the left or right pointers of the root node will be modified.

Comment: Added comment on the confusing part. Please contact me back if still not clear, or mark question as answered. Note: There might be other ways to get things done. It has been more than 30 years I dealt with binary trees, when I was doing by BsC in CS back in the 80's.